# Behaviour of Abnormal termnation of process having shared memory

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, shared-memory

I am working on a project. In that many processes are sharing memory means they are using same physical memory address in kernel.

Just an Ex:-
there could be several processes in the system running the bash command shell. Rather than have several copies of bash, one in each processes virtual address space, it is better to have only one copy in physical memory and all of the processes running bash share it.

Now, I am maintaining reference count to know how many processes are using that resource and freeing the resource when the reference count goes to zero on normal termination. But what will happen on abnormal termination??

As I read till so far that if a process gets abnormally terminated then linux releases its resources and clear its memory. So, will it also clear the physical memory which is shared by other processes?? If no, then how should i get to know which process get abnormally terminated (hundreds of process are running and every second new processes are getting created and terminated) as I will have to decrease the reference count otherwise the reference count will never become zero and the resource associated with it will never get free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory is used for data or code. These are two different types or memory areas in terms of control.
It seem you mix these types together in your question.

Processes can share data memory or can use shared libraries. These are done in different ways.

When starting an external process you don't have control over memory where the process code is loaded. That means your example with bash doesn't make sense.

If you use system API to allocate and manipulate shared (data) memory then OS takes care of allocation and deallocation of resources including cleaning up after abnormally terminated processes. You do not need to bother with reference counting yourself.

If you have a system where "every second new processes are getting created and terminated" then you shouldn't probably worry about abnormally terminated processes and resources allocation/deallocation as the the whole situation is **already abnormal**.

You amy probably want to re-think your design or ask a different question.

Comment: I am maintaining reference count as a temp. variable and was releasing the memory shared by several processes when reference count becomes zero. I was worried for abnormal termination as in that case I am unable to decrease reference count value and it will never be zero until I reboot. But like you told that OS will take care of deallocation of resources then my problem is solved.